# (Done) REQ: Reopen How to proceed in new role?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[How to proceed in new role?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183556/how-to-proceed-in-new-role/183566#183566)

This question is answerable after the edit.  The user is a new user and we should cut them a little slack.

Imposter syndrome is very common in the business world, esp in IT, it can be, and should be addressed.

Comment: Lots of imposters in the IT industry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the question and indeed the edit improved it considerably and made it more focused and answerable.

The question had no reopen votes at the moment, but my judgment called that it was ok, so I went ahead and hammered it open :)